# Help with adding extra faces for extruding

Tags: modeling, faces, edges, extrude

So I added an edge loop to my model so I could extrude part of the face out. When I try to select the face I made, it selects the old, larger face that was there.[image]

Comment: Not sure what you did but you certainly didn't add an edge loop. That looks like a bunch of loose edges

Comment: I pressed ctrl+r and added the edge loop? It worked for the rest of the model, not sure what went wrong there

Comment: There seem to be duplicate faces overlapping. You probably added a loop to the inner part of the cup, and now selected the outer part